# How to show App Logo in All Navigation Bar in SwiftUI App

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an app, which displays logo in the center of the NavigationBar in SwiftUI. The app is using NavigationStack in iOS 16. Here is the implementation.

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Detail", value: "Detail")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
            }.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { stringValue in
                DetailView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This displays the heart logo in the center of the NavigationBar but as soon as I go to DetailView, the heart logo is gone. How can I make sure that the heart logo is available on app the navigation bars in the app.

UPDATE: I can solve this problem by creating a custom NavigationContainerView as shown below:

```
struct CustomNavigationView<Header: View, Content: View>: View {
    
    let header: Header
    let content: () -> Content
    
    init(header: Header, content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.header = header
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            
            NavigationStack {
                content()
                    .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { stringValue in
                        Text("Detail")
                    }
            }
            
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        header
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

But this creates a small gap between the NavigationBar and the back button as shown below:

[image]

UPDATE: ZStack approach does not show the image at all.

```
struct CustomNavigationView<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: () -> Content
    
    init(content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            
            NavigationStack {
                content()
                    .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { stringValue in
                        Text("Detail")
                    }
            }
                
        }
    }
}

struct CustomNavigationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            CustomNavigationView {
                Text("DETAIL")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a `ViewModifier` to call in the subviews hold

Comment: So something like subView.setupToolbar(). But what if I have 50 views.

Comment: You call setup toolbar 50 times, there is no way of setting up the principal for everything, Each child is its own thing. The `NavigationStack` is meant to sit at the top.  Putting it in a Stack like you are will cause issues in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is to use instead `ZStack` with top alignment, like

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {      // << here !!
        
        Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            .foregroundColor(.red).zIndex(1)
        
        NavigationStack {
            content()
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { stringValue in
                    Text("Detail")
                }
        }
```

Comment: I added the ZStack but now I cannot even see the heart logo. Updated code in the original question.

Comment: Pardon, forget to add zIndex to put it ahead, or move it below NavigationStack - the latest view is at the top.

Comment: If I don't use NavigationStack then the Image is displayed in the center. If I add the NavigationStack (which I want) then the Image moves to the top. How does this work? What is NavigationStack doing to push the image in the toolbar?

Comment: It stretches ZStack to entire screen